# Python how to get a subset of a two-dimensional array?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two lists:

```
>>> a = ["question1", "question2", "question3", "question4", "question5"]
>>> b = ["php html", "html", "html", "java", "php"]
```

then I obtained a 2D array using:

```
>>> c = (a,b)
```

Now I wish to create a subset of `c` to keep only the rows corresponding to question i to j.

I tried:

```
c[i:j+1][0:1]
```

and many other things, but could not figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> a = ["question1", "question2", "question3", "question4", "question5"]
>>> b = ["php html", "html", "html", "java", "php"]
>>> merged = zip(a, b)
>>> merged[0:2]
[('question1', 'php html'), ('question2', 'html')]
```

You can then obtain the questions and answers separately (if needed) by iterating over the list of tuples.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `zip` function like this

```
a = ["question1", "question2", "question3", "question4", "question5"]
b = ["php html", "html", "html", "java", "php"]
c = (a, b)
print zip(*c)[1:3]
```

**Output**

```
[('question2', 'html'), ('question3', 'html')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Python doesn't really have 2D arrays (numpy does, but that's not the standard library). What you have there is a tuple with two elements, both of which are lists.

You can make a new tuple, which consists of the right slices of the old tuple's elements:

```
newtuple = tuple(elem[i:j+1] for elem in c)
```